# How to call a fragment using a dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a dialog extended class. I want to call a fragment to be displayed on a click of a button. I am using this method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
            SearchingFragment mySearchengine = new SearchingFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, mySearchengine);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        // Perform button logic

    });
```

But, my application crashes.
what I want my application to do is to dismiss the dialog and then call the fragment.

Comment: Please show up your exceptions

Comment: Please post your error log here

Comment: you should make a callback to the activity and the activity should be what changes the fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is to pass back the button event of your dialog fragment to the host activity, check the [Passing Events Back to the Dialog's Host](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents) chapter in the Android dialog documentation. This is not only a good practice, but saves you alot of trouble, when you want to reuse the dialog.